# Is there a NetBeans plugin to add JBoss AS 6 support?

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, jboss, jboss6.x

JBoss 6 AS is released and I would like to test it in the NetBeans IDE.

In NetBeans 6.9.1 the JBoss 6.0.0.Final directory can not be chosen - the error message is "Provide a valid JBoss Application Server 4 or 5 Location"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the time to get it working you can find the information on how to make NetBeans 6.9 work with JBoss 6 [here](http://www.paulomotta.pro.br/2011/05/14/netbeans-6-9-jboss-6-support-to-use-icefaces-2-0/)

Answer (score 2):

it looks like folks have done that in the past: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181753